# How to get perticular digits from the string in android?

Tags: java, android, string

I have one String = GETMSG_m_m_5556 from this I want to read only 5556, means I want to read all the digits after last "_". The string has not fixed length of numbers it may be like, GETMSG_m_m_9898786589 OR GETMSG_m_m_98987865.  So how can I read the numbers after "_"?

Can anyone suggest me the write way.? It may be foolish question but I am stuck on this. I cant get any idea about this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String digits = sampleString.subString(sampleString.lastIndexOf("_"),sampleString.lenght);
```

Get the last index of the char '_' in your string and make a required substring to get the numbers .see [string.subString()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [string.split()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) function and take last string.

```
String[] separated = yourString.split("_");
// Now choose the last array value
```

Comment: Thanks paresh but my string has more than one _ so how its worked? And one more thing I want to get the numbers using StringBuffer, means I want that number in stringBuffer.

Comment: But As you have mentioned in question, you are having 3 times "_" and just last value is varying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using  `StringTokenizer`

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(String);
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
String s = st.nextToken();
if (s.startsWith("_")) {
....
}}
```